# Error when using SVG in the component template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-components

In this example, the error appears in the console: `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M 100,{{$ctrl.test}} L…".   angular.js:3505`
See this error in the browser console (I use last stable Chrome).
The SVG is displayed correctly.

```js
'use strict';

var MyExampleTemplate = {
    template:   '<svg width="200" height="180">' +
                    '<path stroke="orange" stroke-width="10" fill="gold" ' +
                        'd="M 100,{{$ctrl.test}} L 180,160 ' +
                        'L 20,160 z"/>' +
                '</svg>',
    controller: MyExampleController
};

function MyExampleController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.test = 0;
    vm.$onInit = init;
    console.log('Ctrl: %s', vm.test);

    function init() {
        vm.test = 20;
        console.log('Init: %s', vm.test);
    }
}

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .component('myExample', MyExampleTemplate);
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
    <my-example></my-example>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

In this example, I'm trying to change another attribute. No error. The SVG is displayed correctly too.

```js
'use strict';

var MyExampleTemplate = {
    template:   '<svg width="200" height="180">' +
                    '<path stroke="orange" stroke-width="{{$ctrl.test}}0" fill="gold" ' +
                        'd="M 100,20 L 180,160 ' +
                        'L 20,160 z"/>' +
                '</svg>',
    controller: MyExampleController
};

function MyExampleController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.test = 0;
    vm.$onInit = init;
    console.log('Ctrl: %s', vm.test);

    function init() {
        vm.test = 1;
        console.log('Init: %s', vm.test);
    }
}

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .component('myExample', MyExampleTemplate);
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
    <my-example></my-example>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Is it a bug or I can not use the SVG in such a way? How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there are restrictions on the values that are considered valid for certain attributes. This is why Angular has `ngAttr` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes)). You need to change your code like this:

```
<path ... ng-attr-d="M 100,{{$ctrl.test}} L 180,160 L 20,160 z" />
```